# Glossaries entry in heading of book class causes an error

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, glossaries

In the following MWE, an entry from `glossaries` is included in a section title so it gets included in the page heading created by the book class:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\begin{document}
\newglossaryentry{asd}{name={ASD}, description={asd sda das}}

\section{A + S + D: \gls{asd}}

\end{document}
```

This causes the following error on the first `pdflatex` run (even before running `makeglossaries`):

```
! Package glossaries Error: Glossary entry `ASD' has not been defined.

See the glossaries package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.9 \end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Should I just avoid using glossaries entries in chapter and section titles?

Comment: See [I get an error when using a glossary entry in a chapter/section heading or caption](https://www.dickimaw-books.com/cgi-bin/faq.cgi?action=view&categorylabel=glossaries#movingarg).

Comment: Thanks @NicolaTalbot!! It is indeed answered where you said :) From your linked post: "However, even with v4.10 a problem occurs when \MakeUppercase is used in the heading (which occurs by default)". I will use \glsentrytext, \glsentrylong, \glsentryshort or \glsentryfull as I am using just `glossaries` and not `glossaries-extra`. Thanks!